# Color a text with different colors similar to the Google logo?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, text

I am trying to change the color of some text similar to the Google logo of G with 4 colors. I am trying to do this in Photoshop but it seems to be a bit difficult to select and cut a section of one font.

Here is the picture of google logo:

[image: Google logo]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Although Illustrator is more appropriate for this task, this is a simple exercise of "add to" and "remove from" selection.

Comment: This isn't a job for Photoshop really, nor is it a photo editing question. Use vector software instead, like Inkscape (which is free), or Illustrator (not free).

Answer (score 2):

Draw your colors on another layer (or layers), place that layer above your text in the Layers panel and use your text as a clipping mask for you color layer(s).

You can <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> the line between the two layers in the Layers panel to create a clipping mask (or go to *Layer → Create Clipping Mask* with the top layer selected).

Using a clipping mask and keeping the text and color layers separated means you can carry on editing both independently of each other without breaking anything...

[image]

If you have more than one layer making up your colors you simply repeat the process of creating a clipping mask for each layer and they will all be clipped to the bottom layer:

[image]

https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/photoshop/using/revealing-layers-clipping-masks.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **gradient overly** within the **layer style** (Double click the layer to open the window)

Do a **Angle** gradient with the required colors.
But make the colors close to each other to not get the gradient effect from one color to another

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for Photoshop, but in my opinion, it would be easier using vector software like Illustrator or even Inkscape (which is free!).

Start with a character converted to outlines, draw some closed paths above the character, select both, then use the Path operations (Pathfinder in Illustrator) to cut the image apart, and then add some fills.

This is a quick example using Inkscape. The same is possible in Illustrator.

[image]